# How to assign a new column that shows the total number of rows in a file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can anyone help? I want to assign a new column which counts how many rows do I have in a single file.
Here I have file name in each row, you can see that the first 9 rows are in a single file(...block_10.jpg) so I want a new column that shows the total rows in the file.
[image: Here is my dataframe]

I have extracted the values from the data frame using df.iloc

```
X = df.iloc[:,:-1].values # This is all the columns NOT including the last one
Y = df.iloc[:,-1].values # This is the filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_classification['count']=df_classification.groupby('filename')['Name'].transform('count').values
```

Thanks to someone who gave an answer but he deleted it because there was a small error. Please comment to take credit for the answer, sir!